# SolrJ HttpSolrServer throwing NoHttpResponseException during instantiation

Tags: solr, apache-httpclient-4.x, solrj

SolrJ is throwing NoHttpResponseException when trying to instantiate HttpSolrServer.  Anyone knows why?

In the code I do:

```
SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer ("http://localhost:8983/solr/"); // or some other url.
```

and it throws:

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/NoHttpResponseException
```

I'm using Solr and SolrJ 4.1.0

Comment: Is your Solr instance running?

Comment: yes it is running....that was the first thing i thought about coz of the exception name, but yes it i running....

Comment: What happens when you type the same url in a browser?

Comment: the solr admin page comes up.  basically the solr server is up.  I mean, would there be any other reason why the exception would be thrown other than the server is not up and accesible?

Answer (score 6):

I dont know if your problem was the same as mine but i thought that i'm getting the same exception until i noticed that i'm having the exception `noClassFound :NoHttpResponseException` and just by adding this package `httpclient-4.1.3` the issue was solved.
hope this helps.

Comment: Glad that I could help.

Comment: Actually it requires `httpcore` library, but if you use maven `httpclient` is fine as well since it depends on `httpcore`. So `httpcore` would be fetched transitively

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but I used `solrj-4.3.1`. You need `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore` jar on your classpath to resolve this problem.

I used `httpcore-4.2.5.jar`

Answer (score 2):

My problem wasn't even solved after adding httpclient-4.x.x. I added all the libraries being distrubuted by solr-4.4.0 , dist folder. After that my problem got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

you problem was the same as mine.  i solved the problem by adding the package httpclient-*.jar  and the package httpcore-*.jar. i hope this help for you

Answer (score 1):

I to had same problem but after adding the following 3 jars I was able to fix it.
1. **httpclient**
2. **httpcore**
3. **httpmime**

And these suitable jars provided in your respective solr framework.
Example I am using solr4.7.2 and these jars are present in folder as solr-4.7.2\dist\solrj-lib\

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: what explain you needed ?